# Mistakenly Not Setting Values to self.foo

Tags: python

I've only just dipped my toes into the Python pool. I understand how classes and namespaces interact and `del` just removes stuff from scope, and all that goodness.

My question is simple. I made a simple "hello world" (Pygame) app, but made a critical mistake (simple case below):

```
class Cat:
  __name = ""
  def __init__(self, newName):
    __name = newName
  def meow(self):
    print "Hi from {0}".format(self.__name)

c = Cat("Mittens")
c.meow(); # prints: "Hi from "
```

In hindsight, my mistake is obvious: in my method (constructor, here specifically) I assigned a value to `__name` instead of to `__self.name` (which, by the way, should be mangled and private).

I even understand how and why it works -- it's kind of like static scope in Java/C#.

What I don't understand is how to avoid these kinds of tricksy errors. This was obvious, easy, and the result was, in my case, nothing -- things should have worked but nothing happened.

How do Python developers avoid this problem? Is seems like it would be very common.

Comment: The Python interpreter telling me that "__name" is not defined is actually enough information to make me check the code where it should have been set.

Comment: Welcome to the python pool.  It's definitely a nice place to go for a swim :)

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer -- In this case though, the interpretter won't tell you that `self.__name` doesn't exist.  Since `self.__class__.__name` does exist, python will use that.

Comment: I would highly recommend that you not use mangled names like `__name`.  The desire to tightly control how people use your code is a vestige of other programming languages.  Just use regular names.

Comment: @NedBatchelder this is an example to highlight that even with mangling, the field is still accessible. I use `_name` in my real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I would definitely avoid adding `__name` to the class namespace.  Since `__name` is (supposed to be) set by the initializer (`__init__`) unconditionally, there is no point to having a class level `__name`.

e.g.:

```
class Cat:
  def __init__(self, newName):
    __name = newName
  def meow(self):
    print "Hi from {0}".format(self.__name)

c = Cat("Mittens")
c.meow() # prints: "Hi from "
```

Now run the code and you'll get an `AttributeError` which helps to catch these sorts of bugs.

In other words, the purpose of `__init__` in your code is to set `__name` on the new instance being initialized (`self`) via `self.__name = newName`.  In your code, you're providing a "safety net" by setting `__name` on the class.  In python, if an attribute isn't found on the instance, it is then looked up on the class.  However, this "safety net" is actually a bad thing in this case -- you get different behavior than you expected rather than an Exception which could be used to help you track down the bug.

---

As a side note, the way attribute access on an instance works (baring interesting things like `__getattribute__`) is that python first looks on the instance for the attribute, then it searches the class and then it works it's way up the class's method resolution order (which is different for old and new-style classes).

Comment: I think what you're saying is "unlike (C#, Java, etc.) you don't need to declare `_name` before you use it." Is that right?

Comment: @ashes999 -- Not quite.  It gets "declared" when your instance is initialized ...

Comment: can you update your answer to explain this concept? I misunderstood it.

Answer (score 1):

Static analysis tools such as [pep8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8), [pylint](http://www.logilab.org/857), [pyflakes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes) and [flake8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8) can help to certain extent. For example, `pyflakes` would complain about your code (placed in a file named `stack_overflow-2013-03-08.py`):

```
$ pyflakes stack_overflow-2013-03-08.py
stack_overflow-2013-03-08.py:8: local variable '__name' is assigned to but never used
```

But nothing beats a good set of [tests](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html). Needless to say, if you had a test for `Cat.meow` that reasonably covered its range of functionality, you would have caught this problem [right meow](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXPeLctgvQI).